# Sobreposição de dados a percorrer ciclo for

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabela-html

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: tabela formulário]

Esta tabela está dinâmica e funciona tipo formulário, ou seja, o utilizador ao clicar `Novo` é criada uma nova linha com os campos dinâmicos. Ao clicar `Salvar Dados` todas as linhas criadas pelo utilizador são guardadas. Até aí tudo bem. Mas o que estou a fazer é dar a possibilidade de o utilizador inserir Ficheiros, para tal tenho uma `input type="file"` também dinâmica para cada linha (esta a `hidden`), onde vai carregar os dados para o `controller` a partir de um `ajaxSubmit` (estou a trabalhar em ASP MVC 4).

O meu **problema** agora é:
Ao fazer o `ajaxSubmit`, o `javascript` está a sobrepor os dados dos `id's` dinâmicos que tenho para a `input file`. Segue a função:

```
function submitDocCertISCC(numID, DivNrFicha) {
$("#formSaveFile" + numID + "_" + DivNrFicha + "").ajaxSubmit({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#formSaveFile").attr("action"),
    clearForm: true,
    data: { numID: numID, DivNrFicha: DivNrFicha }
});
}
```

Eu chamo a função a cima ao percorrer um ciclo `for` onde vou guardar cada linha da tabela de cada vez, e funciona bem. Agora chega a parte de gravar o ficheiro e só grava o ficheiro da última linha. Pelo que me parece, ele vai para o próximo passo do ciclo `for` sem antes acabar de fazer o `ajaxSubmit`.

Como é que posso contornar isto e que ele obrigue a não saltar no ciclo sem terminar esta função?

**EDIT**

Ciclo `For`:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= window.numAutoDeclaracaoISCC; i++) {

$.getJSON("/Terceiros/saveAutoDeclar", { // Gravar dados da linha
                DivNrFicha: DivNrFicha, dtaEmissao: dtaEmissao, NumAutoDeclar: NumAutoDeclar, DtValid: DtValid, EmitidoPor: EmitidoPor,
                Anexo: Anexo, DtEntregaTec: DtEntregaTec, DtRecepcao: DtRecepcao
            },
            function (result) {
                submitDocCertISCC(i, DivNrFicha); // Fazer submit do form com o ficheiro

            });
        }
```

Comment: Pode mostrar o contexto mais amplo do código?

Comment: Actualizado. No ciclo for não coloquei a carregar os dados a enviar no `.getJSON`, penso que não é importante para a questão

Comment: Aha, agora está claro o problema.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é mesmo o que você suspeitava: como a chamada ajax é assíncrona, seus callbacks estão sendo chamados após o término do ciclo `for`, quando o valor de `i` será `window.numAutoDeclaracaoISCC`. Isso ocorre porque o escopo de `i` é um só, o do contexto onde esse código está (no JavaScript, não existe escopo de bloco, somente de função).

Uma solução simples é adicionar uma função intermediária para capturar (*close over*) cada valor de `i`:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= window.numAutoDeclaracaoISCC; i++) {
    // assume que DivNrFicha é definido aqui
    $.getJSON("/Terceiros/saveAutoDeclar", { // Gravar dados da linha
            DivNrFicha: DivNrFicha,
            dtaEmissao: dtaEmissao,
            NumAutoDeclar: NumAutoDeclar,
            DtValid: DtValid,
            EmitidoPor: EmitidoPor,
            Anexo: Anexo,
            DtEntregaTec: DtEntregaTec,
            DtRecepcao: DtRecepcao
        },
        (function(i, DivNrFicha) {
            return function (result) {
                submitDocCertISCC(i, DivNrFicha); // Fazer submit do form com o ficheiro
            }
        }(i, DivNrFicha));
    });
}
```

Comment: Continua com o mesmo problema. Se introduzir apenas duas linhas ele insere os dois ficheiros, mas no valor do `i` vai `2` nas duas linhas, em vez de `1`, grava e incrementa e depois `2`.

Comment: Tem certeza de que é o `i` e não o `DivNrFicha`? Acho que você precisa passar esse segundo para a função também (vou atualizar a resposta).

Comment: Sim, o `DivNrFicha` contém um número correspondente à "Auto Declaração"

Comment: "*close over*": chamo isso de [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Sim, é uma IIFE. E também uma closure. Usei "close over" como tradução de "capturar".

Answer (score 0):

Use `{async: true}` na chamada de ajaxSubmit(), assim o sistema aguardará o término (`200 OK`) de cada requisição.

```
$("#formSaveFile" + numID + "_" + DivNrFicha + "").ajaxSubmit({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: $("#formSaveFile").attr("action"),
    clearForm: true,
    data: { numID: numID, DivNrFicha: DivNrFicha }
});
```

Comment: Nããããããooooooo! :) Isso vai travar a página até que a requisição seja completada. O ideal seria usar callbacks.

Comment: @bfavaretto pensei nisso também, mas parece ser exatamente o problema **para o cenário citado** - claro que poderia ser feito um refatoramento.

Comment: Por acaso não resolve @TiagoCésarOliveira

Comment: @CesarMiguel poderia por favor atualizar sua pergunta com o fonte completo do `for`?

Comment: Já coloquei @TiagoCésarOliveira

Comment: Cara, você tem toda uma chamada assíncrona. Sem testar, pela experiência, acredito que o erro esteja aí. Recomendo, **apenas para fins de verificação**, que transforme sua chamada em getJSON em síncrona (usando .ajax com dataType JSON, por exemplo). Se passar a funcionar como deveria, você tem o diagnóstico montado. Se for isso, no seu lugar, procuraria mudar a lógica para já salvar quando é selecionado o arquivo para upload.